# Polynomial Execution Time Examples

Tags: performance, big-o

Of the following two execution times, which are polynomial and why?

```
I O(n^log n)

II O(log(n^n))
```

I believe only I is polynomial, as II looks to be logarithmic, would this be correct assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By log properties, log(n^n) = n * log(n) which is less than n^2 for large n. Therefore, O(log(n^n)) is contained in O(n^2) and so is in polynomial time.

n^log n can't be bounded by c * n^k for any c, k, as log n is a monotonically growing function, so clearly it cannot be in polynomial time. It is however smaller than 2^n for sufficiently large n (I'll leave this as an exercise to verify) and so is at most exponential.